# Django JsonRequest in generic view always returns a string

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, django-views

(using Django2.0)
This is my first time trying to collaborate with a frond-end developer and I am trying to serialize a Django model from a generic ListView. Even though I manage to send a JsonResponse with my objects as json, they are always a string:

```
"[{\"model\": \"questions.question\", \"pk\": 9535, \"fields\": {\"created\": \"2018-04-14T17:02:38.559Z\", \"modified\": \"2018-04-14T18:04:14.264Z\", \"question\": \"TEST\", \"category\": \"Rules\", \"event\": \"Beyonce\", \"answer\": \"aergaergaergaer\", \"verified\": true, \"verified_by\": [\"someotheruser\"], \"count\": 0, \"user_created\": [\"someuser\"]}}]"
```

the way the front-end developer solved this issue is by calling a JSON.parse(). (see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

**Is this the correct way to do it or should I return the objects without a string?**

If I am wrong and there is a way to do this without the strings here is my view and url:

views.py:

```
from events.models import Event
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse

class EventView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Question
    template_name = 'faq/faq.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        events_list = Event.objects.all()
        context['events_list'] = events_list
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        event = Event.objects.get(event=self.kwargs['event'])
        queryset = Question.objects.filter(event=event)
        return queryset

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('<str:event>/', EventView.as_view(), name='event'),
]
```

What I also tried:

```
def EventRequest(request, **kwargs):
    event = Event.objects.get(event=kwargs['event'])
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(event=event)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    dump = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(dump, content_type='application/json')
```

and:

```
def EventRequest(request, **kwargs):
    event = Event.objects.get(event=kwargs['event'])
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(event=event)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

Once again this could be absolutely correct and the front-end developer should just do a JSON.parse(). Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell, your end is fine. If the front end developer is using an `XMLHttpRequest`, it might be better to use `XMLHttpRequest.responseType = "json"` with an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. JSON is a string notation. It is just a format to represent JavaScript objects and arrays (Python dicts and lists) as a string.

In the frontend you'll have to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it into a JavaScript array (list) or object (dict).

This also holds true when you send JSON from frontend to backend. You use `JSON.stringify()` to covert the JS object to string. Then in the backend you convert that string to a Python object using `json.loads()`.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for clarifying the reverse way of doing it.